# hash in Montypay for flutter

Tags: flutter, payment

After reading this docs I stuck on certain field "hash" how to generate it like the wanted

[image]

```
      String orderNumber = "order-1234";
      String orderAmount = "0.19";
      String orderCurrency = "usd";
      String orderDescription = "Important gift";
      String merchantPass = "merchantPass";
      final inputString =
          '$orderNumber$orderAmount$orderCurrency$orderDescription$merchantPass';
      final utf8Bytes = utf8.encode(inputString);
      final hash = md5.convert(utf8Bytes);
      final hashString = bytesToHex(hash.bytes).toUpperCase();


String bytesToHex(List<int> bytes) {
const hexDigits = '0123456789ABCDEF';
return bytes
    .map((byte) => hexDigits[(byte & 0xff) >> 4] + hexDigits[byte & 0x0f])
    .join('');
```

}

I'm trying to put hashString  in hash field,
but every time the response is

```
{
"error_code": 0,
"error_message": "Request data is invalid.",
"errors": [
    {
        "error_code": 100000,
        "error_message": "hash: Hash is not valid."
    }
]
```

}

and this from postman

[image]

also in collection there is pre request how I can take hash from it
[image]

Any ideas how to make it in the app?!

Answer (score 0):

It should be uppercased first

Example from their docs in PHP:
[image: Example from their docs in PHP]

> Example: Must be SHA1 of MD5 encoded string (**uppercased**): order_number
>
> - order_amount + order_currency + order_description + password